# How to abort unit test from another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I have unit test sample code that basically runs 2 threads: the main test thread and another thread I'm launching that is supposed to fail the test execution after some time (this is basically a timeout thread)

Code is as follows:

```
[TestClass]
public class SomeTestClass
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public void BeforeTest()
    {
        var task = new Task(abortIfTestStilRunsAfterTimeout);
        task.Start();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }

    private void abortIfTestStilRunsAfterTimeout()
    {
        Assert.Fail("timeout passed!");

    }
}
```

Well, I was expecting that the `TestMethod()` test should fail but what actually happens is that the task thread that runs the `Assert.Fail` method gets an exception while the other thread keeps on running and the test passes.

I'm looking for a way to fail the test method

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test?

Comment: i have 100's of test cases that runs on my system. this system is a multithreaded network application. when the test case dose is to send my app messages in a correct order and then it waits for specific order of replies

Comment: So if some test takes more than 5000ms you would fail it manually?

Comment: Usually, when you have threads, the type of testing you are doing is not considered "unit testing". Unit testing is for testing deterministic cases, while threading is non-deterministic.

Comment: i beg to differ - threading is very deterministic, u start a thread, it does something very specific and then it dies. if u have timeout thread and sufficient locks in your application there shouldn't be any problems

Comment: I'm sory if this sounds strange, but what signals success and what signals fail?  Each test case is run by a separate thead, right?  So, you create and start the thread that runs a test case.  How do you know it has completed successfully?  Does the test thread call some 'OnComplete' delegate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try and get a reference to the test thread and call `Abort()` on it. You can pass an exception state object to `Abort()` which you can use to pass a fail message:

```
[TestClass]
public class SomeTestClass
{
    Thread testThread;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void BeforeTest()
    {
        testThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
        var task = new Task(abortIfTestStilRunsAfterTimeout);
        task.Start();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException e)
        {
             Assert.Fail((string)e.ExceptionState);
        }
    }

    private void abortIfTestStilRunsAfterTimeout()
    {
        testThread.Abort("timeout passed!");
    }
}
```

In case you do not want to modify some 100 tests you can use a tool like PostSharp to modify your test cases by inserting the `try {} catch {}` logic around each test case for you. All it boils down to is to write an attribute and decorate you test assembly with it (it's called Aspect Oriented Programming and the framework in PostSharp for that is called Laos).

Comment: i've tried this method too, but assertion description does not get passed by using this method. i'm worried that if someone else will encounter a problem with my tests he\she won't be able to understand what caused this abortion

Comment: @Tzahi: You can pass a message via `Abort` - I adjusted the code.

Comment: it's better than the last suggestion but will require me to modify 100's of tests. don't they have anything less intrusive?

Comment: @Tzahi: You can use PostSharp to do that for you.

Comment: @Tzahi: The free starter edition supports method level aspects and that should be all you need. Alternatively you can try Afterthought: https://github.com/vc3/Afterthought or CciSharp: http://ccisamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CciSharp&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 1):

The idea is simple - just run main test logic in a task/thread, and just put timeout handling code in the test method/test initialize. Some kind of [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control):

```
// Test class level
ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);                                

[TestMethod]     
public void TestMethod()     
{                     
    // start waiting task
    Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // Test Body HERE!
            // ... 

            // if test passed - set event explicitly
            mre.Set();
        });


    // Timeout handling logic, 
    // !!! I believe you can put it once in the TestInitialize, just check
    // whether Assert.Fail() fails the test when called from TestInitialize
    mre.WaitOne(5000);

    // Check whether ManualResetEvent was set explicitly or was timeouted
    if (!mre.WaitOne(0))
    {
        task.Dispose();
        Assert.Fail("Timeout");
    }                
}
```

PS: Regarding `WaitOne(0)` trick, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189907.aspx):

> If millisecondsTimeout is zero, the method does not block. It tests
>   the state of the wait handle and returns immediately.

Comment: auto rest events is unfortunately not the solution in this case. i've written this test case because i have a very complicated tests and in some cases i found that tests get stuck, this means that nothing happens for a while. my intention is to run a new timeout thread each time a test start, when test completed this thread will get destroyed, but if the thread timeout has passed it should fail this test and allow other tests to keep running (i have a few 100's...). your solution require me to modify all my tests and won't work since i cant block the execution of my test method

Comment: this solution requires me to write a lot of code in my tests, this is exactly the reason why I've wanted to use thread that's being launched from class init and not test method. this also requires me to write 2 methods for each test - 1 for the deceleration part so that i'll see it on test manager and another for implementation (instead of writing anonymous code)

Comment: 'when test completed this thread will get destroyed' - how do you know that the test is complete and you can desroy the timeout thread?

Comment: @Tzai: you have to wrap each test in the following code block: `Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>         { ... TEST HERE  });`, I believe not a big deal

Comment: martin - each task i start from the before test method will start with canceletion token, when a test exit i'll have [TestCleanup] attribute on new method that will cancel the timeout task. by this i'll know that my test was completed (with pass \ fail status - it doesn't really matter)

Comment: sll - it\s not a big deal when writing 1 test, when needing to fix the code of about 300 tests - it's a different ball game :(

Comment: This is like refactoring of the legacy code, sometimes you have to do such kind of job once to move to new foundation. But let's think few minutes more, perhaps something could be simplified...

Answer (score 0):

This post is somewhat old, but recently I was having a similar issue.

My solution is different:

> use the NUnit TimeoutAttribute

See NUnit documentation here: 
NUnit 2.5: https://nunit.org/docs/2.5/timeout.html 
NUnit 3.0: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Timeout-Attribute

Answer (score 0):

A solution leveraging [`TimeoutAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.timeoutattribute) and/or [`TestContext.CancellationTokenSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testcontext.cancellationtokensource):

```cs
[TestClass]
public class SomeTestClass
{
    private Task abortTask;

    // Test runner will set this automatically.
    public TestContext Context { get; set; }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void BeforeTest()
    {
        this.abortTask = Task.Run(
            () => 
            {
                this.WaitForAbort();
                this.Context.CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            });
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public Task TestMethod1()
    {
        // Cancellation triggered by manual abort logic.
        this.TestWithCancellation(Context.CancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [Timeout(5000)]
    public Task TestMethod2()
    {
        // Cancellation triggered automatically by the runner after 5 sec.
        this.TestWithCancellation(Context.CancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }

    private void WaitForAbort()
    {
        // Concurrently check for some abort condition...
    }

    private void TestWithCancellation(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Do your test, but pass/respect the token!
    }
}
```